# Doctrine Complex Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a complex inner join using doctrine. My query is:

```
    SELECT purchased_items.previewurl, purchased_items.ordernumber, orders.shipByDate, CustomerDesign.designData, fos_user.email
    FROM FYPEmailsBundle:purchased_items purchased_items
    INNER JOIN purchased_items.orders orders
    INNER JOIN orders.CustomerDesign CustomerDesign
    INNER JOIN CustomerDesign.User fos_user
```

When I run the query I get Class FYP\EmailsBundle\Entity\orders has no field or association named designData. My CustomerDesign entity looks like:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="orders", inversedBy="CustomerDesign")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="orderID", referencedColumnName="customerID")
*/
protected $orders;
```

My orders Entity looks like:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="orders", mappedBy="CustomerDesign")
*/
protected $CustomerDesign;
```

How do you handle a complex inner join with Doctrine?

Comment: Do the tables relate to one another in some way? As written, those are CROSS JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your one to many annotation on Orders is backwards to me. This should be correct.

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomerDesign", mappedBy="orders")
*/
protected $CustomerDesign;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. I did have it backwards, I'm struggling with doctrine.

Comment: No problems, I recommend this doc, it's still useful to me and I've been developing with symfony/doctrine for some time now -> http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html